# Fade to another background image in Android

Tags: android, fade

I've been making an Android app which starts out with a particular background image, then switches to another after the user presses a button. Now I'm trying to have the second image fade in when the user presses the button. I have an XML animation file called fadein, with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="5000">
</alpha>
</set>
```

The only information I've been able to find on this matter pertain to ImageView, instead of android:background, as I am using. How do I implement the fadein animation on a background image?

Comment: A background is simply the image a `View` has for its background. As far as I know, there is nothing you can do other than set it. If you want to change the background of a `View` using animations, you may need to implement your own `View` that is backed by something like a `ImageView` so you can apply animations to it. This is because creating an `Animation` from XML, as you wish to do here, will only apply to `View` objects.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Do you know how I could make an `ImageView` fullscreen then?

Comment: Not sure if making an `ImageView` "fullscreen" is the best way to describe it, but try using the `match_parent` tag for the `layout_width` and `layout_height` on the `ImageView`.